# Export grid to excel that contain huge data

Tags: asp.net

I am display data in gridview, that has paging. when exporting to excel,all entries are not coming.Suppose I click on page1, then all entry from page1,not all pages.Then I have to click on page2,for page2 entry.Does all entry from all pages will come in single click on button.Does it right way,I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your export function, disable paging on the grid and rebind it. Afterwards, just turn paging back on and rebind it again.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass the entire dataset to your export function, instead of the filtered one that I am assuming you are passing currently.

Comment: In one function suppose f1(), I am executing a query.Taking that value in dataset and assign dataset object to gridview and bind.Call f1 in starting of function f2(where I writing code for export).

Comment: The query you are executing is returning a full dataset or a partial dataset?  You may need to write another query to retrieve the full dataset before exporting it.

Comment: See I have done like this(sample query).Select col1,col2,col3 from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id =table2.id where table.id='34'.Taking that value in dataset and assign dataset object to gridview and bind.Gridview has default page size is 10.How many record can we take in one excel file.

Comment: 65534 records maximum in an excel file.

Comment: Hey Jon,thanks.In some query more than 1000 record means have to come all data together.No need to click on second page ,right?But this not happening in my case.

Comment: Right, the idea is that you need to get all the data in one dataset, and then export that dataset.  From your explanation, it sounds like you are only exporting a partial dataset.

Comment: I made allowpaging to false,in export function only.It solved my problem.